# Maven - How create project from archetype

Tags: java, maven, mvn-repo

I am new to maven a I have to create project from archetype archetype-2jse-simple-1.1.1, i have it in my local directory. Can you help me what console commands in terminal should I use. I only know that I have to use mvn archetype:generate. I tried it several times but I dont know the run my local archetype.

Answer (score 3):

In maven when using `archetype:generate` you can specify which archetype to use for generating the maven priject.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=<archetype group id> -DarchetypeArtifactId=<archetype artifactid> -DarchetypeVersion=<archetype version>
```

For example if your archetype's groupId is `cz.swigroup` and archetype artifactId is `archetype-2jse-simple` and version is `1.1.1` then the command will be.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=cz.swigroup -DarchetypeArtifactId=archetype-2jse-simple -DarchetypeVersion=1.1.1
```

**Update**

Since the artifact is not from central repository and it is from `https://artifactory.cs.vsb.cz/libs-release-local/` you have to add the repo in the `~/.m2/settings.xml`

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>maven-repositories</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>artifactory.cs.vsb.cz</id>
                    <name>artifactory.cs.vsb.cz</name>
                    <url>https://artifactory.cs.vsb.cz/libs-release-local/</url>
                </repository>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>maven-repositories</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the command runs, but i get message that it cant find my archetype, I added URL but it still doesnt work, probadly I need to create m2/settings.xml

Comment: If have the archetype project in your machine, run `mvn install` from the archetype project folder. then run the above command in my ansewr.

Comment: I have downloaded .jar and .pom from site of my professor, when I run mvn install it says there is no POM in my directory, but I have my .pom file in directory.

Comment: thank you for you support, I created that m2/settings file, also i used `mvn install:install-file` to update the archetype-catalog. I tried to use `mvn install` and `mvn archetype generate` with errors every time

Comment: I am still lost about it, probadly I have to go to professor.